# Measurement protocol and two tracking IDs

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We're looking to set up measurement protocol requests to import non PII CRM data to Google Analytics. This will be tied to a client ID that is stored in the CRM and the measurement protocol request would be set to a non-interaction hit populating user scoped custom dimensions.

The CRM data is populated via two portals one for a global market and one for China, with each having their own property number.

The issue currently faced is it is unknown which portal the CRM data originated from and therefore which tracking ID to use with the measurement protocol request.

Even with the request being a non-interaction hit, if a request was made to both tracking IDs, what would happen with the data if the client ID didn't already exist?

- Would a new user still be created?
- Would it be disregarded?
- Are there any ramifications of such actions?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure my assumptions on this are correct I tested this (i.e. sending a single non-interaction event with a set clientid) with an empty view, and the answers are:

- a new user is created
- no
- yes, there is at least one ramification since GA counted a user, but no session (I guess since technically there was no interaction). This looks rather odd in the reports. Also of course no pageview for that user.

Comment: Ok thanks. In the request did you include ni=1 so that it was a non-interaction hit? Are you using the user explorer to confirm user was created? Interestingly I don't see a user under user explorer but the custom dimension was set with 0 sessions against so what has it set it against, the user? I wonder why it's not showing under the user explorer

Comment: I do not see a user in the user explorer (which is to be expected since the explorer reports sessions, of which there are none). However I see a user in the "audience" report overview. I used the non-interaction flag. I will test without the flag to see what difference it makes.